# Why do SaaS apps not pay sales tax in my state?

Tags: united-states, taxes, software, sales-tax

I have noticed many SaaS apps I use do not include sales tax on their invoices in my state (New York).

For example, on a recent Heroku invoice, I see this written:

> Heroku is not required to, and does not, collect your state’s sales
>   or use tax. Purchases are not tax-exempt merely because a seller is
>   not required to collect the tax. Your state’s law requires a purchaser
>   to review untaxed purchases and, if any tax is owed, file a use tax
>   return and pay any tax due.

However, I see that Heroku would almost certainly qualify as having economic nexus in NY State, according to this link: https://quaderno.io/resources/us-economic-nexus-guide/

Why do they not add sales tax to the bill?

Comment: Is the specific service they offer taxed in New York? Are you sure they have more than $300k in sales and 100 transactions in New York since Jan 15, 2019 (that's when the law went into effect, but might use a different period)? Likely unrelated, but isn't Heroku  PaaS?

Comment: Good point - I forgot the law was effected to recently. I am not sure they have recorded 300k yet in sales (though - so perhaps they are "waiting" until the moment they do to start adding sales tax... Not sure. They are also owned by Salesforce.com. And yes, it is a PaaS but under NY's definition, I believe it would count as a licensed software.

Comment: Feels hard to answer why they specifically aren't required to collect, but I'd imagine it's one of those two reasons.